# PyTesseract not working

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, ocr, pytesser

After installing PyTesseract, I went into my Mac's terminal to make sure it works. I got it to output into a text file perfectly find, but after running this code in Enthought Canopy:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/Users/Nelson/Desktop/Projects/R6S Statistics/OCR/ocr-test.png'))
```

I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'ImagingDecoder' object has no attribute 'pulls_fd'
```

This error comes from the PIL file:

```
/Users/Nelson/Desktop/Canopy/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by restarting my Jupyter notebook kernel. I performed a `pip install --upgrade scikit-image` in the middle of a notebook session and got this error. The upgrade installed a newer version of PIL (v4.0) but the previously installed (v3.2) version has already been loaded into memory.